# Kubectl proxy shows certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: proxy, kubernetes, kubectl

## Question

What is the cause of the **http: proxy error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority** when starting **kubectl proxy** with a specific IP of the node?

```
kubectl proxy --port=8001 --address=172.31.0.16 --accept-hosts='172.31.0.16'

I1222 09:00:03.471836   16775 logs.go:41] http: proxy error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")
```

Comment: Similar error: `Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`, fixed by just authenticating `gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-name --zone us-eastx-y --project my-project`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the cause. Has not executed below.

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```