# http: proxy error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes

I am starting kubernetes proxy using this command:

```
kubectl proxy --port=8001 --address=172.19.104.231 --accept-hosts='^*$'
```

try to access kubernetes api using curl command in master node like this:

```
curl http://172.19.104.231:8001
```

but the server side give this tips:

```
[root@ops001 ~]# kubectl proxy --address=172.19.104.231 --port=8001 --accept-hosts='^*$'
Please enter Username: admin
Please enter Password: Starting to serve on 172.19.104.231:8001
I0119 23:19:32.724990    4274 log.go:172] http: proxy error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
I0119 23:19:59.951800    4274 log.go:172] http: proxy error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
I0119 23:22:13.782977    4274 log.go:172] http: proxy error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
I0119 23:22:22.517052    4274 log.go:172] http: proxy error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

what should I to fix this problem and access kubernetes success?I already read [Kubectl proxy shows certificate signed by unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938669/kubectl-proxy-shows-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority), and I am not using kubeadmin to install kubernetes and has no admin.conf file. I am also read this [kubectl unable to connect to server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234295/kubectl-unable-to-connect-to-server-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authori), but my problem is different.this is my `~/.kube/config`:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 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
    server: https://172.19.104.231:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: admin
  name: kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

Comment: can you post your kubeconfig

Comment: Provide more details. Are you On-Prem or baremetal(kubeadm, minikube). What K8s and OS version are you using. Any interesting entries when use `journalctl -u kubelet`?